# Microphone for a project

Tags: audio, breadboard

I'm just wondering whether or not this [Electret Microphone Amplifier - MAX4466](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1063) will be sufficient enough for the project that I'm planning?

**My project**

I plan to connect the microphone up and accept input. This input is then converted to a .wav file (using Python). Once the .wav file is generated, it then passes to a library that I've written in C++ which handles the .wav file and then sends a signal back to the Pi.

The programming isn't a problem, it's just essentially the hardware. If I purchased this, as well as a breadboard, and found some designs out there, would this therefore work? I don't want to connect a USB microphone up.

Comment: @ppumkin Excuse me?

Comment: Please read the help section on to ask well formed questions. Embedding signatures and thanking in advance is not allowed. The up vote mechanism is a way of thanking the user and accepting an answer marks your answer as solved, regarding the person who helped you correctly. I edited and removed your signature.

Comment: Just curious, do you have any source regarding the raw data to a .wav file? I've been looking around trying to understand how to output the raw data into this format and have not found anything.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [this I2C ADC add on](http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/14/Delta-Sigma-Pi-18-bit-Analogue-to-Digital-converter) for the Pi. You can then directly solder the Microphone onto this expansion board without the use of breadboard. It is slightly pricey but it looks like a good quality and well thought out design. So its Plug and play.

[image]

But you can obviously go the experimental route and buy your own I2C ADC (MCP3008) chip, wire it up on your breadboard for a fraction of the price. [I think this is great tutorial on how to start.](http://hertaville.com/2013/07/24/interfacing-an-spi-adc-mcp3008-chip-to-the-raspberry-pi-using-c/)

[image]

As a prototyping requirement you would not like to solder and de solder things constantly, you could use PCB headers. These should be 2.5mm single headers. Male or female whatever suits you best and use prototyping cables. Solder these on to the PCB and peripherals and then you can then plug things in and out as you require.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this :) I'm really liking this: I2C ADC add on However my only concern is soldering on the mic as i didn't really want to do any soldering at this stage :(

Comment: You can solder on headers and use prototyping cables instead. Even crocodile clips works well. Answer updated.

Comment: Is the I2C ADC add on a good approach? Are there any examples of working microphone projects using this approach?

Comment: Loads. Just search the Internet. Microphones are analog you just need some a cap and resistor to balance the input and then you can use some software to capture the wave using i2c.

Comment: I think it may be even possible to connect the microphone directly to the Analog pins. You use caps and resistors to adjust the gain, etc.

Comment: @ppumkin wich analog inputs ? i've been looking to documentation for two days and i can't see a way to have analog inputs ... please explain. I have a raspberry Pi3 model B...

Comment: Analog inputs of the DAC/ADC chip.. not on the Pi

Answer (score 3):

You would need some kind of recording hardware (sound card, ADC, etc), as it is the Pi does not have anywhere you can just connect this to.

But providing you have a suitable analogue to digital interface for the Pi, then yes, this should work fine.

Comment: Would you recommend me /some how/ creating my own ADC convertor on a board? Or are there some products which would allow me to do this? I.e. http://www.adafruit.com/products/1085

Comment: A USB sound card would be the easiest, not really sure of the status of PCM/I2S on the GPIO header, but it [looks](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=21716) like ther may still be work to be done on that.

Comment: That ADC would work, you should be able to sample a single differential channel to record to WAV from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand this, however, if I purchased a usb sound card; then I would not be able to connect a microphone to a breadboard.. Would I? -- Just seen your last post, this is great! Do you think there will be any tutorials out there to connect this to a breadboard?

Comment: You could easily modify a cable. And yes, most certainly.

Comment: I've found this: http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/17/ADC-Pi-V2---Raspberry-Pi-Analogue-to-Digital-converter would this be suitable for receiving audio?

Comment: It could, I would go for the Adafruit: it is cheaper and you get the full 16 bit resolution.

Comment: Valid point. But, I'm struggling to find anywhere out there that has any information on connecting this, as well as a microphone to the breadboard in order to receive audio! Any suggestions?

Comment: On connecting which part of it, analogue or digital?

Comment: Adafruit actually have tutorials for almost all of their products: http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts