# Using Electret Microphone to get Audio-Input on R-PI

Tags: raspbian

I am new to electronics and not sure how to handle an electret microphone with an R-PI.

I want to develop some active noise cancellation with my Raspberry (Model B). So I thought USB-Microphone would be to slow for achieving this. But I can't find a well written tutorial for introducing the electret microphone amp (from Arduino) to my R-PI.

Do I need further components? Someone can give me a detailed explanation how to use this microphone with R-PI and how to configure it? Or is this microphone a bad decision for my purpose?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that the Pi does not have the means to sample analogue signals. So you will need additional hardware to read the microphone - which is the point where one has to ask whether that offers benefits over the obvious usb-soundcard approach. Please check this out http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9618/microphone-for-a-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a USB microphone or sound card, start with that, you will probably find it doesn't actually use a lot of processing power to get the samples.

That way you can get straight on to writing your application!

Your best non-USB alternative is probably SPI, but that is [not straightforward](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=109643)